# Top 1 of Multiple Rows in 1 table? (Access/SQL)

Tags: ms-access

I'm having trouble completing an assignment.

The question asks "What is the highest rated event for all TV channels on file?"

Events, Event Quality, and Channels are all separate tables connected by a single intermediary table.  I am trying to make a query that shows only the top 1 event (sorted by quality) *for each channel.*  I know how to make a query that shows the top quality event for a single specified channel, but I'm unsure how to show each channel's highest quality event in a single query.  I'm pretty sure I need to use a query within a query, I'm having trouble coming up with the first query to insert as a filter into the final query.

I tried to find a similar question via search but I had a hard time locating an answer.  Sorry if this has been asked before.

Comment: It is rather diffuicult to answer a question without more information about the structure of the tables (tables including "intemediary table"/relationships/table fields). It sounds like you have to use aggregate functions. Do some research for GROUP BY and HAVING Functions. Then put your specific problems (with code/SQL string) in this question that an appropriate answer can be provided.

Comment: Think of TOP 1 as only returning the first record in an ordered list.  GROUP BY is much more powerful as it can turn many rows into a single row with counts and sums of field in the orginal set of rows...

Comment: Could you post a simple SELECT that returns all the data in your tables (you just have to do the JOINS, basically)?

Comment: I appreciate the answers guys.  I didn't want to pass the code or screenshots of the work as it felt too much like cheating.  I was more looking for "hints" than an explicit answer, though I understand that goes against the spirit of this resource.

These responses are very helpful and I will work with what you all have provided to try and continue my assignment, then return with more information that will lead to a definite answer to maintain the integrity/usefulness of this question.  I just don't want to "cheat" and have all the work done for me.

Comment: I can write a query that only includes event quality and channel, and use an aggregate of MAX on event quality, and it will only show the top quality events per each channel.  That much is great and what I want.  However, I want to match the NAMES of the event to the actual event quality.  When I add the events themselves into the query, my list blows up from one event per channel to multiple events per channel -- the MAX aggregate ceases to do anything (doesn't matter if its group by or max at that point, same result is returned).

Comment: I'm just not sure how to get past this point.  It's driving me crazy.  I found http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html as a resource (TOP n Records per Group) but I'm having trouble making sense of it and applying it to my problem, as the example deals with just a single table, whereas I am using four, and I'm really only familiar with making queries via a GUI and have hardly had any hands on with SQL, so it's difficult for me to understand.